# SQLAlchemy counting all rows, I want specific rows

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In words, I'm trying to achieve this goal:

"Get 5 comments where comment.post_id == self.context.id and sort those by the highest number of Comment_Vote.vote_type == 'like' "

Currently the models are:

```
vote_enum = ENUM('like', 'dislike', name='vote_enum', create_type=False)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__='users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = Column(String(65), nullable=False)
    comments = relationship('Comment', backref='user')
    comment_vote = relationship('Comment_Vote', backref='user')
    posts=relationship('Post', backref='user')

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    body= Column(String(1500))
    comments= relationship('Comment',backref='post', order_by='desc(Comment.date_created)', lazy='dynamic')
    owner_id= Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))

class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__='comment'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    body= Column(String(500))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('comment.id'))
    post_id= Column(Integer, ForeignKey('post.id'))
    user_id= Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    children = relationship("Comment",
            backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[id]),
            lazy='dynamic'
            )
    del_flag= Column(Boolean, default=False)
    date_created= Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    last_edited= Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    comment_vote= relationship("Comment_Vote", backref="comment", lazy='dynamic')

class Comment_Vote(Base):
    __tablename__='comment_vote'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id= Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    comment_id= Column(Integer, ForeignKey('comment.id'))
    vote_type = Column('vote_enum', vote_enum)

    @classmethod
    def total_likes(cls, comment_id, session):
        return session.query(cls).filter(cls.id == comment_id).first().comment_vote.filter(Comment_Vote.vote_type=='like').count()
```

My functioning query is:

```
f = session.query(Comment_Vote.comment_id, funcfilter(func.count(1), Comment_Vote.vote_type == 'like').label('total_likes')).group_by(Comment_Vote.comment_id).subquery()

comments = session.query(Comment, f.c.total_likes).join(f, Comment.id==f.c.comment_id).filter(Comment.post_id == self.context.id).order_by('total_likes DESC').limit(5)
```

This has the nasty side effect of counting ALL comment_vote 'likes', even for comments that aren't relevant to that post.

I'd be really grateful for a bit of advice on how to rearrange this so it didn't have to count everything first. What I want may not be possible, and I'm working mostly within the ORM.

DB behind the SQLAlchemy is Postgresql.

Comment: What's `funcfilter`?

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.funcfilter

Another way of saying filter(), pretty much. It was done because putting the filter after wasn't counting the enum properly.

Comment: Heh, I thought it was something you had defined. You can try doing a join directly instead of doing a join to a subquery: `SELECT comment.id, count(*) AS total_likes FROM comment JOIN comment_vote ON comment.id = comment_id WHERE Comment.post_id = :id AND vote_type = 'like' GROUP BY comment.id`.

Comment: I'm so terrible at converting sql into sqla statements. Give me a bit and I'll update as soon as I get it working.

Comment: `session.query(Comment, func.count().label('total_likes')).join(Comment_Vote, and_(Comment_Vote.comment_id == Comment.id, Comment.post_id == self.context.id, Comment_Vote.vote_type=='like')).group_by(Comment.id).order_by('total_likes DESC').limit(5)`

Something like that? It works, but worse. Having trouble replicating your WHERE statements, and that's probably the kicker.

Comment: The equivalent of `WHERE` is `.filter`. Have you done an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see what the query plan is?

Comment: Explain, yes. Analyze, no. I'll post the raw sql emitted and then tinker with it more.

`SELECT comment.id AS comment_id, comment.body AS comment_body, comment.parent_id AS comment_parent_id, comment.post_id AS comment_post_id, comment.user_id AS comment_user_id, comment.del_flag AS comment_del_flag, comment.date_created AS comment_date_created, count(*) AS total_likes 
FROM comment JOIN comment_vote ON comment_vote.comment_id = comment.id AND comment.post_id = %(post_id_1)s AND comment_vote.vote_enum_1 = %(vote_enum_1_1)s GROUP BY comment.id ORDER BY total_likes DESC 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s`

Comment: Sadly, I'm completely failing here...

Comment: Well, what's the query plan? Is it using appropriate indices?

Comment: `Limit  (cost=20402.06..20402.07 rows=1 width=549)

  ->  Sort  (cost=20402.06..20402.07 rows=1 width=549)
        Sort Key: (count(*)) DESC

        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=20402.04..20402.05 rows=1 width=549)
              Group Key: comment.id

              ->  Hash Join  (cost=11.76..20368.58 rows=6692 width=549)
                    Hash Cond: (comment_vote.comment_id = comment.id)

                    ->  Seq Scan on comment_vote  (cost=0.00..16776.46 rows=936917 width=4)

                          Filter: (vote_enum_1 = 'like'::vote_enum_2)`

Comment: ` ->  Hash  (cost=11.75..11.75 rows=1 width=549)`

   `->  Seq Scan on comment  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=1 width=549)`

    `       Filter: (post_id = 4) `

Comment: I know that's a giant blob, sorry, but that's a post that has 1 comment with 1 like. Don't really know why it's seq_scanning the rest of the 940,000 likes (obviously dummy data). Queries like the OP had the same return numbers everywhere, ie, 250ms or so. These fluctuate, the lows are 170ms, and the high queries with 500k worth of dummy likes are spiking 350ms+. I dunno if this is normal or not, hence my question. None of this feels right.

Comment: Do you have an index on `comment_vote.vote_type`? This is a classic situation where I would recommend denormalizing the data. Depending on how often you run this query, doing a `JOIN` + `GROUP BY` every time is fairly expensive, as you can see, compared to maintaining a `like_count` column.

Comment: I don't think I have an index set. My original data model had a like counter for that reason, I figured a write would be cheaper than a thousand counts...but then some mentors told me I was better off counting. I think I'm going to go back to the counter. This query will be run for every post ever viewed; and views always happen more than likes.

Comment: Could you elaborate how `func.count(1).filter(Comment_Vote.vote_type == 'like')` wasn't counting the enum properly? You should open a bug on that, if it really is misbehaving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a nice place to use a [lateral subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL). It is the "foreach" of SQL, which is to say that a lateral subquery can reference columns of preceding FROM items. Postgresql supports lateral from versions 9.3 and up, [SQLAlchemy from versions 1.1 and up](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#lateral-selects):

```
from sqlalchemy import true

f = session.query(func.count(1).label('total_likes')).\
    filter(Comment_Vote.comment_id == Comment.id,  # References Comment
           Comment_Vote.vote_type == 'like').\
    subquery().\
    lateral()

comments = session.query(Comment, f.c.total_likes).\
    join(f, true()).\
    filter(Comment.post_id == self.context.id).\
    order_by(f.c.total_likes.desc()).\
    limit(5)
```

I moved filtering based on *vote_type* to WHERE clause of the subquery, as it's unnecessary in this case to first fetch all rows and then filter in the aggregate function (which also cannot use indexes).

Of course in this case you could also use a [scalar subquery](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#scalar-selects) in the SELECT output for same effect:

```
f = session.query(func.count(1)).\
    filter(Comment_Vote.comment_id == Comment.id,  # References Comment
           Comment_Vote.vote_type == 'like').\
    label('total_likes')

comments = session.query(Comment, f).\
    filter(Comment.post_id == self.context.id).\
    order_by(f.desc()).\
    limit(5)
```

Comment: I had no idea these even existed; and the lateral query appears to work. Still testing, but small comment queries result in tiny times, large ones are a lot longer than other methods but I figure that's just a side effect. May I ask your opinion on what I should index?

Comment: `Comment.post_id` at least and `Comment_Vote.comment_id`. The latter is imperative, as the performance of the subqueries relies on it. Vote type may not be a good candidate, but that'd depend on how it's distributed.

Comment: Holy crap the speed is unreal (250ms to 3ms). Thanks!

Comment: The reason why your original query beat the lateral and scalar subqueries without the indexes in place is probably that it performed a single seq scan on comment votes, grouped and joined. The lateral or scalar subqueries have to be performed for each comment row. If you have relatively few comments and indexes in place, it should be acceptably fast. For fetching a huge batch of comments (a large fraction of the table) and their votes your original query can still be better.

Comment: It did exactly that; a single seq scan and group/join. Which was why all the ms times were consistently the same. 

Also, in regards to above, I think I just screwed up func.count(), because the issue I was having was that the comparison wasn't occuring; I was getting just a count of Comment.vote_type.